# Create automation to remove workbook password from .xlsx files

Tags: java, php, sql, excel, xslt

I have a scheduler sending me files in an FTP every day. The files are in an excel format and they have a password (workbook password) which is the same for every file.

I want to create an automation that will remove the password from the files. I had the idea of just opening the file using the password and then saving it. I am guessing this will not keep the password in the new file.

I tried (I had tickets here for this purpose) to replicate that using PHPExcel and MACRO but with no success. There is no command in PHP for that and in MACRO, I need to have the file open to run the MACRO.

So, from what I have found the only solution is to use **JExcel API**.

This script should work :

```
Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("/path/to/protected.xls"));
workbook.setProtected(false);
WritableWorkbook copy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("/path/to/unprotected.xls"), workbook);
WritableSheet[] sheets = copy.getSheets();

for (WritableSheet sheet : sheets){
    sheet.getSettings().setProtected(false);
}

copy.write();
copy.close();
```

But I don't know how to make it run. Can I just create a PHP file where I will include this script? In PHP file I was able to include SQL code as well. Is that possible with Java?

I have not used Java for years and I don't remember if I can make this run by creating one file. I will have to download the software and make it run using classes I guess. But I want only a file to run in my server that will take the protected file and save it (with no password).

Any ideas are welcome and I can update the question accordingly.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the program executable on its own by creating an executable jar file.

Are you using an IDE to write the program? There are various methods to generate them for you.

Comment: So, it will be an one off file that will contain this code above and then I can run automate it somehow in myserver? I guess PUTTY is mandatory here to automate the file.

Comment: Yes, it's a single file executable that you can run by calling it. You can then add it into a script you want to use to automate the rest of the work.

Comment: Cool @Brion. So, one .jar file that contains this code. I will try it. Cheers. If you have any other solution as to automate the removal of an excel workbook password, please share your thoughts.

Comment: Just make sure the code snippet you posted is in a proper class with a main method and it should work.

Comment: I forgot everything about JAVA. I will have to download an existing program then and edit it. Otherwise, I will have to download an IDE and run it from there?

Comment: You'll need to install at least the JDK (Development kit), I would suggest an IDE to make it easier if you've forgotten a lot of Java. It will help automate much of it for you.